# How can i chnage variable value when clicked on the button and get this error Unhandled Runtime Error

Tags: reactjs

So I simply created an h1 text and a button. The logic is simple when I click on the button it should mark value from 343 to 373 but it is giving an error the error statement is:
[the error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoqLV.png) 
It's request to help me

I created a marks variable 343 I was supposed to change it later So I simply created a h1 text and a button the logic is simple when I click on the button it should marks value from 343 to 373 but gives an error.

Comment: If you use next.js, then you should add `"use client"` to the very top of your file and the error should be gone.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: what's your function? you should not use `function`  in the event handler it is a JS keyword